# Oracle 12cR2 RMAN - ORA-01547, ORA-01194, RMAN-06054

Tags: oracle, backup, restore, oracle-12c, rman

Oracle 12cR2.

Error:

> channel default: deleting archived log(s)
>
> archived log file name=+RECO/.../thread_1_seq_166200.26582.1054942673
> RECID=62 STAMP=1054943183
>
> archived log file name=+RECO/.../thread_1_seq_166201.11529.1054941077
> thread=1 sequence=166201
>
> channel default: deleting archived log(s)
>
> archived log file name=+RECO/.../thread_2_seq_223357.10403.1054942671
> RECID=58 STAMP=1054943182
>
> unable to find archived log
>
> archived log thread=2 sequence=223358
>
> Oracle Error:
>
> ORA-01547: warning: RECOVER succeeded but OPEN RESETLOGS would get
> error below
>
> ORA-01194: file 4 needs more recovery to be consistent
>
> ORA-01110: data file 4: '+DATA/.../data_d...fno-4'
>
> RMAN-00571:
> ===========================================================
>
> RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS
> ===============
>
> RMAN-00571:
> ===========================================================
>
> RMAN-03002: failure of recover command at 10/28/2020 00:24:13
>
> RMAN-06054: media recovery requesting unknown archived log for thread
> 2 with sequence 223358 and starting SCN of 1871183322646

My commands:

```
restore primary controlfile from '/.../RESTORE/..._controlfile_20201027_....rman';

alter database mount;

restore database preview;

The final output part of 'restore database preview;' command:

recovery will be done up to SCN 1871164140237
Media recovery start SCN is 1871164140237
Recovery must be done beyond SCN 1871183871662 to clear datafile fuzziness
Finished restore at 27-OCT-20


catalog start with '/.../RESTORE/';

run
{
set newname for database to '+DATA/.../%U' ;
set newname for tempfile 1 to '+DATA/.../%U';
set newname for tempfile 2 to '+DATA/.../%U';
set newname for tempfile 3 to '+DATA/.../%U';
set newname for tempfile 4 to '+DATA/.../%U';
set newname for tempfile 5 to '+DATA/.../%U';
set until scn 1871183871663;
restore database;
switch datafile all;
switch tempfile all;
recover database;
}
```

**NOTE:** all of the full database backuppieces, archivelog backups, daily spfile backup and daily controlfile backup are under this path '/.../RESTORE/'.

I setted my limit to scn 1871183871663 (Recovery must be done beyond SCN 1871183871662 to clear datafile fuzziness + 1) but it says "media recovery requesting unknown archived log for thread 2 with sequence 223358 and starting SCN of 1871183322646."

I couldn't find any clear solution. How can I resolve it?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

1871183871663 is bigger than 1871183322646. You do not have the necessary archivelog in the backups for recovering the database beyond SCN 1871183322646.

You simply specified a point in time recovery target that is not included in the backups.

Comment: Hi sir. I edited my question, sorry for missing information. Can you please review again? Best regards.

Comment: @jrdba This still does not change the fact that the necessary archivelog is not included in your backups. With online database backups, when you perform a recovery, you need the archivelogs that where created during the database backup to be able to recover the restored datafiles to a consistent state. To me it seems those archivelog backups are missing. Maybe they are not backed up yet (if you perform datafile and archivelog backups seperately), depends on how you perform your backups.

Comment: Thank you so much for information sir.

Comment: Hi sir, I solved the problem. This backup getting from Data Guard. And it wants to next day's archivelog backup, I catalog and recovered them. It solved.